# how to test a 'redirect' in Nuxt's middleware?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I have a nuxt page that redirects user if a condition fails in middleware, I'd like to test that a redirections occurs.

```js
middleware({ $featureFlag, store, route, redirect }) {
  if (!$featureFlag.isFeatureEnabled()) {
    redirect(`/gfdgfd`);
  }
},
```

However, the test fails:

```js
it('Should redirect to homepage when FT is turned off', () => {
  const $featureFlag = { track: jest.fn(), isFeatureEnabled: () => false };
  const redirect = jest.fn();
  shallowMount(page, {
    store,
    redirect,
    mocks: {
      $route: { query: { token: {} } },
      $auth: { checkSession: jest.fn() },
      $featureFlag,
    },
    methods: {
      getTokenPayload() {
        return {};
      },
    },
  });
  expect(redirect).toBeCalled(); // THIS FAILS saying 'redirect' was called zero times
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try it like this:

```js
import { describe, expect, it } from 'vitest';
import { setup, fetch } from '@nuxt/test-utils';

describe('GET /dashboard', async () => {
    await setup({});

    it('redirects to /login because not authenticated', async () => {
        const { headers } = await fetch('/dashboard', { redirect: 'manual' });
        expect(headers.get('location')).toEqual('/login');
    });
});
```

Find more examples over here: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/blob/main/test/basic.test.ts